# Jquery Dragable Columns

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a set of data (names) and two areas (call them team 1 and team 2).  The user can drag names to the team 1 and team 2 areas (this works and I am using connectwith and list.

What I want to do is have columns in the names are as follows.
Name   |  Position   | Age   |  etc

A user can then drag the names to team 1 or team 2. I only want the name to show up in Team 1 or Team 2, I don't need all the other information.  I have been looking and trying a lot of different things, but cannot figure out how to create columns for the names area that I can then still drag.  Any idea, direction would be great.

Here is the code I am using to display the Names currently (with Position) - but position just shows next to it.

```
<ul id="items1" class="items">
  <?php do { ?>
    <li class="list"> 
        <?php echo $row_RCDdraft['name']?>
     <?php echo $row_RCDdraft['position']?>
     </li>

    <?php } while ($row_RCDdraft = mysql_fetch_assoc($RCDdraft)); ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: might be handy to post all relevant code and create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Does the php code have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/pells/gYcA4/

The php code works fine, it just gets the names and positions from the database. I replaced the php with a couple examples.

I am using the | to show where I would like to split into 2 columns.